# Stored Procedure not working from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have the following stored procedure:

```
alter proc SPCP_ProgramUpdate
    @ID int, 
    @UserID int,
    @Name nvarchar(150),
    @University int,
    @Level tinyint,
    @isActive bit
    as
    update tblUniversityProgram set University_Fkey = @University, Level_Fkey = @Level, Program_Name = @Name, EditDate = GETDATE(), EditUser = @UserID, isActive = @isActive
    where tblUniversityProgram.ID = @ID
```

When I run the stored procedure from SSMS, it works as intended.

However, when I run that stored procedure from ASP.NET using this code:

```
Dim varDbconn As New SqlConnection
Dim varDbcomm As SqlCommand
Dim varDbRead As SqlDataReader
varDbconn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CPDB_ConnectionString").ToString

varDbconn.Open()

If Request.QueryString("program") <> "" Then
    varDbcomm = New SqlCommand("SPCP_ProgramUpdate", varDbconn)
    varDbcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    varDbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Request.QueryString("program")).DbType = DbType.Int32
    varDbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session("UserID")).DbType = DbType.Int32
    varDbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@University", Session("DecryptID")).DbType = DbType.Int32
    varDbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level", ddlLevel.SelectedValue).DbType = DbType.Byte
    varDbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isActive", chkisActive.Checked).DbType = DbType.Boolean
    varDbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txttitle.Text).DbType = DbType.String

    varDbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    varDbcomm.Dispose()

Else
....

End IF

varDbconn.Close()
```

nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to debug it, which means putting a breakpoint on the line `ExecuteNonQuery` and inspect each parameter value and confirm its exactly what it should be. Also you [shouldn't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), rather you should explicitly set the type and precision on all your parameters. You should also include your complete SP code rather than a fragment. And you appear to have no error handling, you should have a try/catch block so you can detect any errors which happen.

Comment: It could be better to use varDbcomm.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType).value = value so you could be precise on your data types and put it in try catch block

Comment: ASP.NET is a web stack, it doesn't connect to databases. That's the job of ADO.NET. You'll find a **lot** of tutorials for it going back to 2002 and *none* of them use the syntax you tried. In *all* of them connections and commands are created inside `using` blocks, never disposed or closed explicitly. If an exception is thrown the connection will remain open, keeping any transactions or locks and blocking other connections

Comment: ADO.NET won't parse strings into integers if you set the `DbType` to `DbType.Int32`. *Changing* the parameter type after you set its value won't parse it or raise any errors either. You'll have to parse the values in your code and set the parsed value to each parameter's `Value` property. Use `Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value=someInt` instead, after parsing the ID.

Comment: Since you appear to be using  `System.Data.SqlClient` use `SqlDbType` not `DbType` For example `varDbcomm.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int) = CInt(Session("UserID"))`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer to your question is that the value you are getting out of the querystring for program is not the Id in your database that you expect.

At the minute, your code is reading in input values and passing them to a stored procedure without any validation of your expected values - missing session for example could cause you all sorts of unexpected issues.

Debug your code and see exactly what parameters you are passing to your DB.  Check your connection string to see that you are hitting the database where you have amended your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. I would use parmaters.Add in place of addwith, but that should not really matter.

Try adding this code right after  you are done setting up the parmaters:

```
    Debug.Print("SQL = " & varDbcomm.CommandText)
    For Each p As SqlParameter In varDbcomm.Parameters
        Debug.Print(p.ParameterName & "->" & p.Value)
    Next
```

That way in the debug window (or immediate depending on VS settings), you see a list of param values, and the parameter names. I suspect one of the session() values is messed up here.